# Microsoft Graph personal account. How to get the users photo?

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

The Live SDK is deprecated and Microsoft says that I should switch to Microsoft Graph. But why is there are personal accounts still not supported with getting the users photo? Only the beta works, but I don't want to use a beta.

Is there another way to get the users photo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the situation is as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) describes:

> **Note** This operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.

If you use the as-of-time-of-writing current stable version 1.0 of Microsoft Graph, the GET photo operation is limited to work and school accounts. This will be sorted out in the next version which is currently in beta but should be released soon as stable.

Using beta for this API should be ok however. Once it is out of beta, you will just switch this operation to use to stable as likely with little downtime, as the API will most likely stay the same.